# When am I supposed to consider a subscription "active" in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

When am I supposed to consider a subscription "active"? When I successfully do my initial `stripe.customers.create` call? Or do I have to wait for an `invoice.payment_succeeded` event some time later?

If it's right after `stripe.customers.create`, does that mean I could then immediately call `stripe.invoices.list`, get the initial invoice, and have that guaranteed to be paid? Because I figure I'd want to save `lines.data[0].period.end` so my database is completely in sync with Stripe's database for when the subscription period ends.

If it's not right after `stripe.customers.create`, then am I supposed to wait to give my users access to the premium content until `invoice.payment_succeeded` happens some time in the future? That seems awkward. And then would I need a special case to ignore `invoice.payment_succeeded` from the initial payment? Or does that not fire for the first payment?

I guess I am very confused about all this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the [Create Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_subscription) API for a plan without a trial you get a [subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#subscription_object) object back which means your subscription is now considered active and if you check the `status` attribute it would be set to `active`
 You can then use the `current_period_end` to know when the next invoice is supposed to be created.
The documentation for this attribute says:

> End of the current period that the subscription has been invoiced for. At the end of this period, a new invoice will be created.

If you have a trial period then you need to wait for the event `customer.subscription.updated` where `status` becomes `active`

Comment: Thanks! I also just noticed that you get the subscription object back even when you create a subscription for a new customer (using Create Customer not Create Subscription).